# Node JS ERROR: "the request could not be satisfied"

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post, aws-lambda

I am using Node JS and trying to call Lambda function from AWS.
I get the ERROR: The request could not be satisfied 
Status: 403

```
var opts = {
  host: 'myhost.amazonaws.com',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  service: 'execute-api',
  path: '/mypath',
  method: 'POST',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }   
};

var req = http.request(opts, function(res){
  console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (body){
    console.log('Body: ' + body);
   });
});

req.on('error',function(e){
  console.log('problem with request: '+ e.message);
});

req.end();
```

I dont know if my syntax is wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know anything about AWS services, but usually a 403 error code means "forbidden", so it should  have something to do with security concerns, fail to authenticate against server or something like that

Try to execute the query from a browser or using cUrl or wget. If it fails too, it's not you syntax, it's a security concern

Comment: Thanks, I tried to pull the request using postman, I have information back, but when I use the same thing in node js, I keep getting this error.

Comment: Could you provide the detailed request and response ( except for credentials,of course) for both cases?

Comment: When I use Postman, i get the response back all data I need, but not with my code.

Comment: OK . Can't help you much without more info. But If i were you, i would capture each and every header from request on and response from both methods. and start comparing them. Its a an http request. there's not an inifinity of posibilities, son eventually , you'll find the difference.

Comment: I think I get it works. The problem I have is security stuff like you mentioned earlier. I use aws4 for the signature v4. The documentation in AWS is not really clear.

Answer (score -2):

use https rather then http and I hope that will work.